# Safely converting 1 WEI to the current ETH/USD Chainlink price

Tags: solidity, chainlink, price, data-feeds, convert

Let c be the current floating point price of ETH/USD precise to 8 decimal places.

Since Solidity cannot store floating points, getting the current price of ETH/USD from Chainlink's data feed returns c * 10 ** 8.

In Solidity, given that 1 ETH = 10 ** 18 WEI and that 1 ETH = c * 10 ** 8 "USD" from Chainlink, what are some ways to represent the current "USD" price of 1 WEI?

Comment: Why do you need the price of 1 wei? You could store the price of 1 eth and do the same computations. You'll need to divide or multiply by 10^18 when appropriate.